# Electric field lines are radially outwards from a sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry

> $^5$ If you doubt that $\mathbf{E}$ is radial, consider the
> alternative. Suppose, say, that it points due east, at the
> "equator." But the orientation of the equator is perfectly
> arbitrary—nothing is spinning here, so there is no natural
> "north-south" axis—any argument purporting to show that
> $\mathbf{E}$ points east could just as well be used to
> show it points west, or north, or any other direction.
> The only *unique*   direction on a sphere is radial.

This is a cut out from DJ Griffiths *Introduction to Electrodynamics*
(footnote on page 72), in which he describes why the electric field lines come radially outwards form the sphere. I have read it many a times but still not getting what he is trying to say. I am not able to imagine what he is trying to say through this paragraph.

I want a pictorial representation of what he is trying to say here ,or else if you can make it clear through your words that even fine for me.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all is he saying is that a sphere presents exactly the same appearance regardless of its orientation. Given that, you cannot in fact say how a pure sphere is oriented, since all orientations are equivalent. That is quite different from a cylinder say. It follows that the electric field lines must extend radially in all directions, because that is the only unambiguous orientation that is possible with a sphere. You could not imagine, for example, all the field lines being parallel with the equator of the sphere, because a sphere does not have a single equator. Likewise you could not say that the field lines all ran to the left of the sphere, because a sphere does not have a unique left.

Answer (score 0):

DJ Griffith uses the word equator and then has to go onto describe that he is talking about a sphere that is not spinning.

All he is trying to say is that for a charged sphere, due to symmetry, there is no reason for the field to point anywhere else but towards the middle of the sphere or away from it.  If the sphere is positive, the direction of the electric field will be away.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that the field must be radial for symmetry reasons.
A non radial field would introduce a directional asymmetry.

This is because in such a case, at each spatial point you need to chose a component of the field in a tangential direction. Given that the sphere is totally symmetric, how are you going to chose that special direction? there is nothing in the problem that would allow you to do that. For instance, will the field point upwards or leftwards? There is no logical reason to chose one over the other, so the solution cannot involve any tangential component for the field, at any point.

Answer (score 0):

The author is trying to convince you that the electric field
lines of a charged sphere need to point exactly in radial direction.
[image]

He argues that the field lines will neither curl to the
left nor to the right side, just because there is no reason
which makes one direction more likely than the opposite
direction.
[image]
[image]